# Ejecutar un servicio cada cierta cantidad de tiempo

Tags: java, android, android-studio

mi consulta es la siguiente. Estoy intentando realizar un servicio que muestre un mensaje en el LogCat cada 1 minuto por ejemplo. Estuve leyendo un poco sobre esto pero creo que necesito una mano. Los servicios siempre funcionan cuando el telefono este con la pantalla apagada/o en background? Como debería hacer para llamar el servicio nuevamente después de pasado un minuto?
El código lo tengo asi ahora:

```
public class MiServicio extends Service{

  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
  }
}

public void onCreate(){
  super.onCreate();
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
  Log.d("MiServicio", "Servicio corriendo...");
  // Este es el mensaje que quiero mostrar cada minuto como prueba
}

public void onDestroy(){
  super.onDestroy();
  Log.d("MiServicio", "El Servicio se detuvo.");
}
```

Lo tengo declarado para que inicie en mi MainActivity así:

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MiServicio.class));
```

He leído que debo usar un TimerTask pero no tengo mucha idea de como inicializarlo todo dentro de mi servicio. Supongo que debe ser en el onStart. También me gustaría saber si es conveniente detener el servicio alguna vez o no importa que quede siempre sin detenerse. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Depende el tipo de servicio que quieras ejecutar aunque te recomiendo usar JobDispatcher: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Es tán simple como:

```
Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
    .setService(MyJobService.class) // the JobService that will be called
    .setTag("my-unique-tag")        // uniquely identifies the job
    .build();

dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

Comment: Hola Juan gracias por tu respuesta y disculpa la demora. Estuve investigando un poco mas y logré ejecutar el servicio cada cierto tiempo incluso si la app esta en background pero tengo un problema. Si tengo el teléfono desconectado del android studio el Servicio no corre, ahora si lo conecto y hago debug de la app ahi si se ejecuta. Tienes alguna idea del porqué de esto? Gracias

Comment: ¿Con qué lo hiciste al final? Ten en cuenta que el task-killer de android va a ir quitando los servicios que no crea prioritarios. Prueba el job-dispatcher que te comento y seguro que te irá bien